# Custom Adapter not showing any data on ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

I need a custom adapter for my listView. It needs to be passed to a ASyncTask which will get some data from a RSS feed and then hopefully set that data (at the moment Title and Date, both strings) to the row.

The code I came up with is as follow but it's not doing anything with the adapter.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ListView listOne;
    private ListView listTwo;
    RssListViewAdapter adapterOne;
    RssListViewAdapter adapterTwo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rss_layout);

        //Connect all three columns to their ListViews
        listOne = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOne);
        listTwo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTwo);

        //Create both adapaters
        //TODO: Make custom adapater
        adapterOne = new RssListViewAdapter(this);
        adapterTwo = new RssListViewAdapter(this);


        //Class once for each column. Pass feed URL and Adapter.
        new GetRssFeed("http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/index", adapterOne, listOne).execute();
        new GetRssFeed("http://feeds.skynews.com/feeds/rss/home.xml", adapterTwo, listTwo).execute();

    }



}
```

**GetRssFeed.java**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by jameskrawczyk on 07/04/16.
 */
public class GetRssFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{

    String url;
    RssListViewAdapter adapter;
    ListView listToUse;

    public GetRssFeed(String urlInput, RssListViewAdapter adapterInput, ListView listInput)
    {
        this.url = urlInput;
        this.adapter = adapterInput;
        this.listToUse = listInput;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(url);
            Integer i = 0;

            adapterItem adaptItem = new adapterItem();

            for (RssItem item : rssReader.getItems())
            {
                adaptItem.setHeader(item.getTitle());
                adaptItem.setDate(item.getDate());
                adapter.add(adaptItem);
                i++;
                if(i == 7)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Error Parsing Data", e + "");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        listToUse.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

**RssItem**

```
public class RssItem {
    String title;
    String description;
    String link;
    String imageUrl;
    String pubDate;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public String getDate(){return pubDate;}

    public void setLink(String link) {this.link = link;}

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setDate(String pubDate) {this.pubDate = pubDate;}
}
```

**RssListViewAdapater**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RssListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<adapterItem> {

    private final Context context;
    private adapterItem itemsArrayList;

    public RssListViewAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, R.layout.basic_list_item);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_list_item, parent, false);


        TextView headerView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.headerName);
        TextView dateView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);

        headerView.setText(itemsArrayList.getHeader());
        dateView.setText(itemsArrayList.getDate());


        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(adapterItem theData)
    {
        this.itemsArrayList = theData;
    }
}
```

**adapterItem**

```
public class adapterItem {

    private String header;
    private String date;

    public adapterItem() {
        super();
        this.header = header;
        this.date = date;
    }


    public void setHeader(String head)
    {
        header = head;
    }

    public void setDate(String dat)
    {
        date = dat;
    }

    public String getHeader()
    {
        return header;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding items to your `itemsArrayList`?

Comment: @vrundpurohit In the `for` loop in `GetRssFeed` I created a `adapterItem` and add the data to it then pass it to the adapter with `adapter.add(adaptItem)` which has had the add function overridden to add the data to `itemsArrayList`

Comment: you are taking only object of your adapter item. its not arraylist actually

Comment: @vrundpurohit Ok, but what does that translate to. The whole thing is wrong?

Comment: look for my Answer. NO wait I thought you are using BaseAdapter. sorry.

Comment: @vrundpurohit I could be using BaseAdapter if that's easier? I was using ArrayAdapter because the example code of the RSS library I'm using did in their example.

Comment: let me prepare for you. wait for my Answer.

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk may i know Whether RSSReader is Custom Class or any library class

Comment: According to the code, only the last added adapterItem can be shown.

Comment: @Vishwa It's this https://github.com/ShirwaM/Simplistic-RSS

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk i added my answer please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `doInBackground` of `GetRssFeed` you instantiate an `adapterItem` outside `for` loop, this results in only the last `RssItem` being added to the adapter. I think you should instantiate every `adapterItem` inside the `for` loop.

```
for (RssItem item : rssReader.getItems())
{
    adapterItem adaptItem = new adapterItem();
    adaptItem.setHeader(item.getTitle());
    adaptItem.setDate(item.getDate());
    adapter.add(adaptItem);
    i++;
    if(i == 7)
    {
       break;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile it seems you don't override `add` method of `RssListViewAdapater` correctly. In fact you don't have to override `add` at all. The `ArrayAdapter` will handle it for you.

Comment: This gave a null reference error on itemsArrayList in RssListViewAdapter

Comment: You can delete the `itemsArrayList` and in `getView` use `getItem(position)` to obtain the rss item.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BaseAdapter`

```
public class TestBaseAdap extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<adapterItem> itemsArrayList;

public TestBaseAdap(ArrayList<String> itemsArrayList) {
    super();
    this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemsArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_list_item, parent, false);


    TextView headerView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.headerName);
    TextView dateView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);

    headerView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getHeader());
    dateView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getDate());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

You just need to take one gobal `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<adapterItem> mArrayList = new ArrayList<adapterItem>();
```

and then in your asyncTask add like this.

```
mArrayList.add(adaptItem);
```

And finally set your adapter like this.

```
listToUse.setAdapter(new TestBaseAdap(mArrayList));
```

Done.

Comment: Where is the `ArrayList<adapterItem> mArrayList = new ArrayList<adapterItem>();` going? At the top of GetRssFeed instead of the `RssListViewAdapter adapter;`

Comment: in your MainActivity. outside onCreate

Comment: I've tried that but the AsyncTask class can't see it. Also the `RssListViewAdapter` is through errors because the constructor contains `ArrayList<String>`, should that be `ArrayList<adapterItem>`?

Comment: Ok, so I moved GetRssFeed class into MainActivity as a sub class. Made the changes. Duplicated it as I need to run it for two different ListView's and with mArrayList being hardcoded into the .add function I need a second one with a nArrayList for the second column. However now I get a error with `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

Replace

```
adapter.add(adaptItem);
```

code as

```
adapter.addDatas(adaptItem);
```

in **GetRssFeed.java** and replace your **RssListViewAdapter.java** adapter class as

```
public class RssListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final Context context;
private ArrayList<adapterItem> itemsArrayList;


public RssListViewAdapter(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    itemsArrayList=new ArrayList<adapterItem>();

}

public void addDatas(adapterItem item){
    itemsArrayList.add(item);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return getItem(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemsArrayList.size();
}




@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic_list_item, parent, false);


    TextView headerView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.headerName);
    TextView dateView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);

    headerView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getHeader());
    dateView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getDate());
    return rowView;
}


}
```

by Defalut the **[RssReader](http://github.com/ShirwaM/Simplistic-RSS)** doesn't read pubDate from xml.If you wish to read pubDate in **[RSSReader](http://github.com/ShirwaM/Simplistic-RSS)** please copy the code and replace it with **RssHandler.java**

**RssHandler.Java**

```
public class RssHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private List<RssItem> rssItemList;
private RssItem currentItem;
private boolean parsingTitle;
private boolean parsingLink;
private boolean parsingDescription;
private boolean parsingPubDate;
public RssHandler() {
    //Initializes a new ArrayList that will hold all the generated RSS items.
    rssItemList = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
}

public List<RssItem> getRssItemList() {
    return rssItemList;
}


//Called when an opening tag is reached, such as <item> or <title>
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("item"))
        currentItem = new RssItem();
    else if (qName.equals("title"))
        parsingTitle = true;
    else if (qName.equals("link"))
        parsingLink = true;
    else if (qName.equals("description"))
        parsingDescription = true;
    else if(qName.equals("pubDate"))
        parsingPubDate=true;
    else if (qName.equals("media:thumbnail") || qName.equals("media:content") || qName.equals("image")) {
        if (attributes.getValue("url") != null)
            currentItem.setImageUrl(attributes.getValue("url"));

    }
}

//Called when a closing tag is reached, such as </item> or </title>
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("item")) {
        //End of an item so add the currentItem to the list of items.
        rssItemList.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } else if (qName.equals("title"))
        parsingTitle = false;
    else if (qName.equals("link"))
        parsingLink = false;
    else if (qName.equals("description"))
        parsingDescription = false;
    else if(qName.equals("pubDate"))
        parsingPubDate=false;
}

//Goes through character by character when parsing whats inside of a tag.
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (currentItem != null) {
        //If parsingTitle is true, then that means we are inside a <title> tag so the text is the title of an item.
        if (parsingTitle)
            currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
            //If parsingLink is true, then that means we are inside a <link> tag so the text is the link of an item.
        else if (parsingLink)
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            //If parsingDescription is true, then that means we are inside a <description> tag so the text is the description of an item.
        else if (parsingDescription)
            currentItem.setDescription(new String(ch, start, length));
        else if(parsingPubDate)
            currentItem.setDate(new String(ch,start,length));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have had just implemented shhp's fix, which worked, but yours looks awesome too. Nice catch on the RssHandler, I had actually already changed that just left it out of my sample code as it wasn't directly relevant to the question.

Comment: Both are valid answers I think but since I already implemented shhp's I haven't had a chance to test yours. I might change the accepted answer to yours if I get a chance to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Have same problem.
In android 4.1 everything is visible in rows.
But in android 6 is empty rows.
I fck my mind. But find why.

Just add text color

`android:textColor="#000"`